# genmsg dependency - em

Tags: ros, genmsg, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've installed genmsg package on my windows machine and is not able to run. template_tools.py in genmsg depends on module em, which I don't have. Could you please point me tot he place, where I can get this module from.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37082/genmsg-dependency---em/) by [dunduk](https://answers.ros.org/users/2602/dunduk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2012-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fount it. It is empy package, which is available at http://www.alcyone.com/software/empy/

---

Originally posted by [dunduk](https://answers.ros.org/users/2602/dunduk/) with karma: 28 on 2012-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0